# How can I compare 2 different records based on 2 different criteria within a group in oracle?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I need to modify the following code to search for groups where one surv is null and the other is not.  Currently, the query returns groups where both surv is populated. I am looking all groups where the surv for one record A does not match an id in the other record B, but only in cases where the surv in record B is null.

```
SELECT *
FROM MY_TABLE t3
WHERE t3.GROUP_id IN (
SELECT t1.GROUP_id
FROM MY_TABLE t1, MY_TABLE t2
WHERE t1.id <> t2.id
AND t1.GROUP_id = t2.GROUP_id
AND t1.id <> t2.surv
AND t2.id <> t1.surv
);
```

This is returning differences where both survs are populated.  What am I missing?

edit:

```
---------------------------------
| group   |  id   |  surv        |
----------------------------------
|   1     | 1     |  null        |
|   1|    | 2     |    1         |
|   2     | 3     |    107       |
|   2     | 4     |  null        |
|   3     | 5     |  89          |
|   3     | 6     |  89          |
----------------------------------
```

return

```
---------------------------------
| group   |  id   |  surv        |
----------------------------------
|   2     | 3     |    107       |
|   2     | 4     |  null        |
----------------------------------
```

reason: 
group 1 has id 1 matches to surv of the second record; as such we do not want it returned.

group 2, id 3 has a surv that does not match the ID of the other record.  Along with this, the second surv field is null.  This is what we need returned.

group 3, both have a surv of not null.  These are not needed.

edit 2: I eventually came up with this query:

```
SELECT cluster_id, oidmu, survoid
FROM MY_TABLE t3
WHERE t3.GROUP_id IN (
  SELECT t1.GROUP_id
  FROM MY_TABLE t1, MY_TABLE t2
  WHERE t1.ID <> t2.ID
  AND t1.GROUP_id = t2.GROUP_id
  AND (t1.ID <> t2.SURV and t1.SURV is null)
);
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff The original has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

add `and t2.surv is null` to your query.

```
SELECT *
FROM MY_TABLE t3
WHERE t3.GROUP_id IN (
SELECT t1.GROUP_id
FROM MY_TABLE t1, MY_TABLE t2
WHERE t1.id <> t2.id
AND t1.GROUP_id = t2.GROUP_id
AND t1.id <> t2.surv
AND t2.id <> t1.surv
and t2.surv is null
);
```

Comment: I think we need `and (t2.surv is null or t1.surv is null) and not (t2.surv is null and t2.surv is null)`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the *groups*, perhaps an aggregation will do:

```
SELECT t.GROUP_ID
FROM MY_TABLE t
GROUP BY GROUP_ID
HAVING COUNT(surv) > 0 AND      -- at least one is not null
       COUNT(surv) < COUNT(*);  -- at least one is null
```

Actually, even if you do need the original rows, you could do this with analytic functions:

```
SELECT t.GROUP_ID
FROM (SELECT t.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY GROUP_ID) as cnt,
             COUNT(surv) OVER (PARTITION BY GROUP_ID) as cnt_surv
      FROM MY_TABLE t
     ) t
WHERE cnt_surv > 0 and cnt_surv < cnt
```

Comment: This is still returning all groups where t1.id = t2.surv.  I am trying to get groups wehre t1.id <> t2.surv.